# Memory address out of bounds error in MIPS

Tags: mips

I used the following code to print a hello world message but when run an error saying 'Memory address out of bounds' pops up. Why does this happen?

```
.text

main:


la $v0, hello_msg
li $v0, 4
syscall

#Data storage

.data

hello_msg : .asciiz "Hello World\n\n"
```

Comment: Both `la` and `li` are loading to `$v0`. Did you mean `$a0` in the first case?

Comment: Thanks. $a0 worked perfectly fine. why can we not use $v0 when loading a text as we do for integers?

Comment: Well, you can if you would actually do something with it. `$v0` gets immediately overwritten to value `4` after it was pointing to the address of `hello_msg`. In any case, 'service 4' expects `$a0` to point to the text to be printed. And the `syscall` instruction itself expects `$v0` to point to a valid service number (`4` in this case). I'm using http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/Mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html as reference (note that I have no experience with MIPS whatsoever).